# JSON to Generic Spatial Java Object

Tags: java, json

Can anyone suggest a library or approach to deserializing a JSON string to a Java Object which has a Geometry (eg JTS) and a list of attributes?

I have several data sources, which I'd like to be able to query and show on a map along with their attribute data. The ways I've seen involve creating a specific Java Object for each data type (eg AutoBean with getName(), getDescription() etc.). What I'm after is to be able to have 1 object regardless of what the attributes are (as I don't know them ahead of time and there will be many of them)

I'd like to be able to say something along the lines of:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
o.setGeometry(SomeJsonLibrary.readGeometry(json)); //read Geometry
o.setAttributes(someJsonLibrary.readAttributes(json)); //read all other attributes
```

Any suggestions/alternatives welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to turn your JSON into a map.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly does look like you are converting your json to a map.

By the way, this line can be omitted and you can iterate through your map without having it in the list.

`List<Map<String, Object>> features = (List<Map<String, Object>>) mapped.get("features");`

My preference would be Gson (just that I am familiar with Gson). Example Code:

```
Gson gson=new Gson(); 
String json = "your-json";
Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
map=(Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for parsing the "geometry"?

Comment: I don't think parsing the "geometry" (if this is a valid json string) should be a problem. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper):

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> mapped = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        List<Map<String, Object>> features = (List<Map<String, Object>>) mapped.get("features");
        for (Map<String, Object> feature : features) {
            Map<String, Object> attributes = (Map<String, Object>) feature.get("attributes");//for ArcGIS
            Map<String, Object> properties = (Map<String, Object>) feature.get("properties");//for OGC
            Map<String, Object> geometry = (Map<String, Object>) feature.get("geometry");//TODO deserialize geometry
            //do stuff
        }
```

If anyone has a better solution/suggestion, please let me know.